# Extracting arguments of JavaScript function from HTML page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing an HTML page with several **script** blocks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // some code
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    foo(arg1, arg2);
    // some code
</script>
```

I need to extract arguments of the **foo** function - 'arg1' and 'arg2'. Currently I can obtain inner content of the **script** tag:

```
def parse_foo(pageContent):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageContent)
    scriptTags = soup.find_all('script')
    for script in scriptTags:
        tagContent = script.get_text()
        if tagContent.count('foo') > 0:
            return tagContent
    return ''
```

Is there any way to get arguments using BeautifulSoup or should I use regular expression?

Comment: Whatever you decide, don't use regex.

Comment: Why do you need the arguments?

Comment: @That1Guy Please justify why `/^\s*foo\((.*)\);$/` won't work?

Comment: @That1Guy I'm scraping a website. Arguments of this function are strings with JSON data.

Comment: @Brian I'm saying it won't work. I'm saying its a bad idea. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @Vladimir The reason I ask is because if you're attempting to imitate the javascript in Python with the same arguments, there may be better ways. I'm curious what you'll be doing with the arguments. Are you planning on storing them or using them in some way?

Comment: @That1Guy using the data from these arguments I can compose URL's of new pages for downloading and parsing.

Comment: I would suggest looking into Selenium http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pyesprima](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyesprima/1.0.0) is a port of Esprima, "a high performance, standard-compliant ECMAScript parser written in ECMAScript". Fortunately, it's easy to use. Unfortunately, it's a bit slow.

There's even an online parser tool to use: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

When I input `foo(arg1,arg2);`, this comes back:

```
{
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ExpressionStatement",
            "expression": {
                "type": "CallExpression",
                "callee": {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "name": "foo"
                },
                "arguments": [
                    {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "name": "arg1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "name": "arg2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Tree:

```
                ExpressionStatement
                        |
                   expression
                 /      |     \
type=callExpression   callee   arguments
                        |       
                    name=foo
```

1. Look for a ExpressionStatement with a expression.callee.name called "foo".
2. Return ExpressionStatement's arguments.raw (you need to provide the "raw" option as True, see docs)

Comment: My task is not performance critical, so this is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is concerned only with tags, attributes of tags, and the subtree of tags under a tag.
From its point of view, your whole javascript is just text.

If your javascript code is reliably very restricted indeed, you may get by with regular expressions.
If it is even a little more complicated, though, that may be the road to hell.

The logical step then would be to use a javascript parser.
Either a Python one ([pyesprima](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyesprima/1.0.0)) or any other that you feed and 
ask via interprocess communication.